# Golang one request multiple responses

Tags: angularjs, ajax, go, websocket

I am trying to implement a web server handles a large query. The response of a single request is huge. SO instead of sending the large response all at once, I would like to chop it into many pieces, and sending them individually. For instance, I have an array of elements, instead of sending a response contains the entire array, I would like to send responses contain only single element.

What are my options here? Ajax seems cannot handle this kind of work. Do I have to work with socket, websocket? What about streaming response?

I am using golang + angular, any library or resources recommended?

Comment: You have to continue making requests. A webserver cannot just send data to a client unless you have something like a websocket which is constantly open. I would say, what you want to implement is pagenation. In the request, add query parameters for an offset and limit. Have the client iteratively make requests until there is no data left, increasing the offset by the limit for each request. The backend should always return an array, when there is no data at the given offset, the array should be empty which informs the client that it's done paging over the data.

Comment: You can also use the length of the returned array to know when you're done. If length < limit then you know you got the remaining results and you can stop making requests.

Comment: Yeah pagination would be the way to go, else use websockets and broadcast to a room when data is ready. If you want to work with sockets, then have a look at socket.io . Pagination on sockets also seems like an option as you simple use virtual get and post request instead of the actual thing.

Comment: @evanmcdonnal: downside of using the length is that, in the special case where remaining = limit, you get an array back where length = limit, but the next query (and next page you display) will have zero elements in it.  In this case, your page will think there's another page worth of results, and thus have a "next" button, but that button will either fail or display a page with no results (depending on how you code it).

Comment: The way we did it in my last position was return a JSON object with a field that has the list of items, and then fields echoing the limit and offset provided, and lastly a field indicating total results for the query.  This allows a single JSON response to hold all of the data necessary to determine if there's any results left, and how many pages of them there are if so (and how many pages have been viewed thus far, as well).

Comment: @ishaan The goal of this is to reduce the amount of waiting time for user. Therefore, I need to send partial result before the entire array is available.

Comment: @Kaedys when I send out the json, I have no idea what the entire data looks like as the query is still going on.

Comment: When you send the partial json, add an extra object that tells the client it's still incomplete, so the client waits for the object to complete. Keep pushing to the open websocket till there is no more data and send the complete flag, trigger an event on JS side of things to show the user data, or complete a promise or whatever you're doing. Socket.io has methods like `sockets.io.on('activity', callback)`, so they may come in handy.

Comment: you know that "Chunked Transfer Encoding" lets you send the first bit of the response, start processing it at the user agent, and keep sending more pieces later?

Comment: I routinely upload and download multi-gigabyte requests.  Don't split it up into multiple http requests if it makes the code significantly more complicated.

You should be streaming data.  This means that you don't realize huge arrays into memory either for send or receive.  You iterate objects to write the huge list, and parse the huge list (out to disk one by one if necessary).  You can use multipart/form-data to cut it up as well.  If you spread across multiple http requests, then you create a mess that you will need to fix later.

Comment: @Rob I need support parse only part of the JSON. Otherwise, the client would still have to wait for the entire response before parsing it.

Comment: that's a valid strategy.  but it's one imposed by how you parse it.  if you had a state machine that wrote '[' then a then ',' then b, etc... and finally ends with ']', you use a small constant amount of memory that is independent of array size.  You can parse this way as well.  This is the difference between a stream parser (ie: event based parse) vs a DOM parse; a common distinction with xml parsing libraries.

Answer (score 0):

I am using beego and in the backend part I use []map[string]interface{} data type to handle large data. it response multiple object that can be handle in angular.